# How to execute a script within a subfolder of a directory in path

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, path, environment-variables

Consider the following folder structure:

```
$ tree ~/test_path
test_path
`-- sub_folder
    `-- script.sh

1 directory, 1 file
```

Let's say that you have added `test_path` to your path by
`export PATH=$PATH:~/test_path`

```
$ whereis sub_folder
sub_folder: /home/murtraja/test_path/sub_folder
```

Now how to execute script.sh by calling sub_folder/script.sh?

```
$ sub_folder/script.sh
bash: sub_folder/script.sh: No such file or directory
```

EDIT: I don't want to change the call `sub_folder/script.sh` because this is called by another script which I cannot (am avoiding to) change.

Comment: It is necessary to include the directory which contains your script in PATH to be able to run it without specifying the path.

Comment: Yes, that could be done, but I don't want to change the call `sub_folder/script.sh` because this is called by another script which I cannot change

Comment: Add this to your `~/.bashrc`: `function sub_folder/script.sh { (cd ~/test_path; command sub_folder/script.sh); }` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't, but depending on the set of constraints you're facing, there might be another way to handle it.

Long answer: When a command name contains at least one slash character, it treated as a path to the executable (i.e. it doesn't search the directories in `$PATH`). With the command name `sub_folder/script.sh`, it contains a slash, but doesn't *start with* a slash, so it'll be resolved relative to the current working directory.

So there are a couple of possibilities for making this work:

- If you can `cd` to `~/test_path` before running this, it'll find it directly. Of course, this may break other things (i.e. anything else that uses relative paths and/or plain filenames and expects them to be resolved somewhere else). Also, be sure to [check for errors when you `cd`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164), or the script could execute in an unexpected directory, with unexpected consequences.
- If the script needs to execute from a different working directory, you might be able to create a symbolic link from `sub_folder` in that working directory to `~/test_path/sub_folder`. But depending on where the script's working directory is, this may be impossible or unsafe. I'd avoid using this option if possible.

There's also an option that depends on a weird/nonstandard feature of bash: the ability to define function names with slash in them. But this has weird limitations depending on the version of bash you have:

- You can define a function like this:

  ```
   sub_folder/script.sh() { ~/test_path/sub_folder/script.sh "$@"; }
  ```

  and then either use `export -f sub_folder/script.sh` (so bash subprocesses inherit it), or do this in a wrapper script and then `source` the script you can't change from there (so it's the same shell, and inheritance isn't necessary).

  Difficulty: some versions of bash refuse to export functions with weird names, and some refuse to inherit them. So the `export` method might or might not work (and might break unexpectedly due to an update). The `source` method might be better, but also might cause other trouble.

If there's any way at all to change the other script, that'd really be the best option.

Comment: Excellent answer, could you also provide the different things that I could do, if I had access to that script and was able to change it? Like for example `cmd=\`whereis sub_folder | cut -d ' ' -f2\`/script.sh`
And then use like `$cmd $arg1 $arg2`

Comment: @MurtazaRaja I'd avoid (mis)using `PATH` for this -- either add `~/test_path/sub_folder` itself to `PATH` and then just run `script.sh` in the script, or create a different environment variable to refer to the location for this (e.g. `export SCRIPT_PATH=~/test_path/sub_folder` and then use `"$SCRIPT_PATH/script.sh"` to run it). (Note: I generally recommend against using all-caps variables to avoid conflicts with the various all-caps names that have special functions, but in this case you'd essentially be creating your own special-function var, so it seems appropriate).

Answer (score -2):

Since you've added it to your path, you can just call the script by name. It should also let you tab complete as well.

```
$ ./script.sh
```

Comment: But it's not in OP's `PATH`. `~/test_path` is in their `PATH`, but the script is in `~/test_path/sub_folder`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Yes thank you for understanding my problem

Comment: I had the same test script in two places. One was the subfolder I mistakenly thought was running from there on an Ubuntu machine. The other was in a folder directly in my path so it was running that same file instead of the nested version. That explains the incorrect results. My apologies.